# Regular expression to match only lowercase letters

Tags: regex, cocoa

I am trying to match all strings that contain only characters within a-z with a regex in Objective C. I have found several proposed solutions online but none really seems to work (or I am probably missing something).

I have tried the following and I can't understand why it doesn't work :

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex =[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-z]*\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = 0;


NSString* testword = @"testword";

numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:testword
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [testword length])];

NSLog(@"%@ %i", testword, (int)numberOfMatches);
```

and the output is : testword 2.

I am looking to understand regex and I am aware that there are other methods to solve my problem so please don't give a solution using other methods. Thanks!

Comment: please add your desired input and output. also describe what problem you're currently dealing with.

Comment: My problem is to get numberOfMatches to allow me to differentiate a word made only of characters a-z or A-Z from those that also contain any other character (like a number of a punctuation mark).

A possible input would be testword above and I would have expected 1 as an output. I have no idea why the output is 2.

So I would like : "testword" to output 1 and "1 testword" or "test+word" to output 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the combination of *\\b in the regex

\b matches word boundaries and has 0 length
[a-z]* can be length 0 to anything

so the first match is "testword" + wordboundary
the second match is "" + wordboundary

The fix is to require at least one letter by changing the * to a +

\b will match just before punctuation as well. since you include punctuation in your 'words' you can't use word boundaries(\b) anymore. In this case white space or end of string work. You will also need to add start of string or white space to work.

```
(?:^|\\s)[a-z]+(?:\\s|$)
```

Based on your statement of wanting lower case letters only a second problem exists. The NSRegularExpression is constructed with the NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive option. You should use 0 if you truly care about case.